# machine learning with asymmetric training data frequencies

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling

I have about a million rows of data being collected every day, and I am trying to predict a government figure which is released on a less frequent basis, about once a month.  Compared to a traditional ML training set where each example would have an actual value to use for training, I have much smaller training set.

I'm currently just aggregating my daily data to one "monthly" value, and trying to run a regression against the monthly government figure once it's released.  Unfortunately, I only started collecting this data, so I don't even have enough data to run a simple regression model.

Is there any better way to do this, that would leverage the millions of rows of data I have?  Despite there not being any 'correct answer' for each day of data due to the lower frequency of government data being published?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about capturing sub-month temporal features of your data like volatility, spectrum, number of peaks, weekly trends, etc? There are many ways to capture aggregate information about temporal data, not just a simple average. The question of course is what makes sense i.e. describes your subject domain.

Comment: I have, but without any corresponding data on its correctness, I'm not sure if it would help.  Thanks

Comment: I am afraid I am not getting your line of thinking. What should be correct? The ultimate measure of a usefulness of a feature is whether it helps you to make a better prediction. You can do that only after you do create it and put into a model for evaluation.